# mySQL Count rows for each ID in a table

Tags: mysql, select, sum, multiple-select

Database schema

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | killed | killed_by | killed_uuid | killed_by_uuid |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

`killed` and `killed_by` hold the entity type. eg. "Player", "Environment", "Creature". No specifics.

`killed_uuid` and `killed_by_uuid` are the userID's if a player is involved in the kill.

This table holds kills that happens on my game server. Each kill is stored in a separate row so there are no totals for each player.

**I want to create the totals for each userID and create a leaderboard from them. So basically, count the rows that for each separate UserID.**

I have tried using

```
select killed_by_uuid, count(id)
from kills
where killed='999' AND killed_by='999'
group by killed_by_uuid
order by count(id) desc
```

`999` being the ID that belongs to a player entity kill NOT an actual USERID. But all I get is a single result set:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c676680f-98cb-4893-b1ba-ab5ab59fc272
    [killed_by_uuid] => c676680f-98cb-4893-b1ba-ab5ab59fc272
    [1] => 15
    [count(id)] => 15
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select killer, count(killer) as total_kills
from kills
where killed='player' and killed_by not in (<list of environment ids>)
group by killer
order by total_kills desc, killer
```

Comment: Hurrah for my dense-ness. I should of been fetching the array, it's just stored row by row. Your answer is perfectly correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KILLS WHERE KILLED=? AND KILLED_BY NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ...)
```

Comment: You'll probably want to add an index on column `KILLED` as well.

Comment: Wouldn't that only count a single user?